# $(this) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [ColorPicker Plugin.](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about) I initialized the plugin with following code :

```
$(".colorpic").ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);  <= $(this) not working 
    }
});
```

Now my problem is that `$(this)` is not working in `onchange` event. Help me out please?

Comment: perhaps you need to `bind this` to `onChange`?

Comment: It's possible the plugin doesn't pass its context to the `onChange` method.  Open an issue :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(".colorpic").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $this.css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `this` is a really big problem, since in this case the `this` goes to the function if I am not mistaken.
Try the following:

```
var colorPicker=this;
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $(colorPicker).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex); 
}
```